# Suppress tomcat version disclosure on error page

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Wondering if there's a configuration approach that can be taken with Hybris to achieve the suppression of version number being disclosed in error pages which have no explicit definition in an extensions web.xml

Can this be done using any of the OOTB properties files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure an error page in your storefronts web.xml. Find it here:

```
/mystorefront/web/webroot/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Somewhere in that file there is a tag "error-page". It might look like this:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/path/to/serverError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/path/to/serverError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Keep in mind, that in case of an error you are restrained in the functions you can use. So keep these error pages as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement custom error pages to prevent such unexpected behavior. Mosty it handled at Apache Web Server. Like [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html), [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04).

However, as @Johannes answered, you can also configure in Hybris using **error-page** tag of yourstorefront's **web.xml**

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/error/serverError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>java.lang.Exception</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/error/serverError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not just on the error page but also in headers. See here:

http://www.techstacks.com/howto/suppress-server-identity-in-tomcat.html